# JMeter - Capture all the Matches and Write them into a file

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a regular expression which contains multiple matches (17 to be precise). All of these are to be captured and written to a file.

Match No. -1 is used to capture all the matches

Now, am using a ForEach Controller to iterate over these matches. Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Please help. The screenshots are attached for your reference.

Regards,
Ajith

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpHgo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2m9Z.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfirG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is a red `1` near to yellow exclamation sign in top-right corner of JMeter GUI which means that your test has failed somewhere somehow

   [image]

   so inspect [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) and see what went wrong.
2. JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) are only executed in Sampler context, if you put a Post-Processor under the ForEach Controller and there will be no Samplers under that controller - the Post-Processor **won't be executed**. So I would suggest switching to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) instead.
3. Writing data into a file using Groovy script might be not the best idea because if you run your test with >1 threads (users) you will face a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) resulting in data corruption or loss so it might be a better option to consider using [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) and [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/)